# Problems saving files and creating directory

Tags: dired, filenames, save

I have recently set-up a new Emacs on my OSx 10.15. Every time I try to create a directory in `Dired` with  <kbd>+</kbd> I got a warning telling the files already exist.  Another strange result I got when I try to save a file (here I use for example saving an image file from an EPUB document using `nov-mode`. In this case actually it saves (randomly? and dangerously!) over another file (in this case over `11.November.7z`). In `Dired-mode` I cannot create a directory (it continues to change to another directory). I have recorded two screens.

[overwriting filename](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEFOc.jpg)

[creating directory in dired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is1KX.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Find out the problem. There was an incompatibility between `Helm` and `Ido`I have to activate `helm-mode`. Sorry to bother you.